# css hover drop down parent color

Tags: css

Is there a way to keep the `a:hover {color:#ffffff }` white color also when i'm hovering the sub menu?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lg7q0nen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 95 you can do `.sf-menu li:hover a`

The key is that you are using the `:hover` on the li and traverse further after it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
.sf-menu li a:hover { color:#ffffff; }
```

By this one:

```
.sf-menu li:hover a { color:#ffffff; }
```

```css
/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sf-menu li {
  position: relative;
}
.sf-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.sf-menu > li {
  float: left;
}
.sf-menu li:hover > ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.sf-menu li { text-transform:uppercase; color:#555a60;   }

.sf-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.sf-menu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.sf-menu i { 
  position:absolute;
  margin:1px 4px;
  font-size:18px;
  color:#dfd301;
}

.sf-menu i:hover { color:#ffffff; }


/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.sf-menu {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.sf-menu ul {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  min-width: 12em; /* allow long menu items to determine submenu width */
  *width: 12em; /* no auto sub width for IE7, see white-space comment below */
}
.sf-menu a {
  min-width: 113px;
  text-align: center;
  padding:20px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  zoom: 1; / IE7 /
}
.sf-menu a {
  color: #555a60;
}
.sf-menu li {
  /*background: #BDD2FF;*/
  white-space: nowrap; /* no need for Supersubs plugin */
  *white-space: normal; /* ...unless you support IE7 (let it wrap) */
  -webkit-transition: background .2s;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.sf-menu li ul li a { padding:10px; text-align:left; color:#ffffff; }
.sf-menu li ul li a:hover { color:#ffffff; }

.sf-menu li ul li { background:#777777; color:#ffffff; }

.sf-menu ul li {
  min-width:180px;
  text-transform:uppercase; color:#555a60;  
}
.sf-menu ul ul li {
  background: #9AAEDB; 
}
.sf-menu li:hover,
.sf-menu li.sfHover {
  background: #b01523;
  color:#ffffff;
  /* only transition out, not in */
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.sf-menu li:hover a { color:#ffffff; }

/*** arrows (for all except IE7) **/
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul {
  padding-right: 2.5em;
  *padding-right: 1em; /* no CSS arrows for IE7 (lack pseudo-elements) */
}
/* styling for both css and generated arrows */
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1em;
  margin-top: -3px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  /* order of following 3 rules important for fallbacks to work */
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #dFeEFF; /* edit this to suit design (no rgba in IE8) */
  border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.sf-arrows > li > .sf-with-ul:focus:after,
.sf-arrows > li:hover > .sf-with-ul:after,
.sf-arrows > .sfHover > .sf-with-ul:after {
  border-top-color: white; /* IE8 fallback colour */
}
/* styling for right-facing arrows */
.sf-arrows ul .sf-with-ul:after {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-right: -3px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #dFeEFF; /* edit this to suit design (no rgba in IE8) */
  border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.sf-arrows ul li > .sf-with-ul:focus:after,
.sf-arrows ul li:hover > .sf-with-ul:after,
.sf-arrows ul .sfHover > .sf-with-ul:after {
  border-left-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sf-menu">
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">blog</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">page</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the :hover on the whole `li`.
I added this at the end of your css and it seems to work.

```
.sf-menu > li:hover > a {
    color: white;
}
```

There's probably a better place to put it, but there was a lot of code there...

http://jsfiddle.net/vvf0shvg/